# Creating chunks of equal size in R using the primary key

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with over 20 millions records. I created chunks so I can load small sets into multiple csv files. The code is working and it's creating n number of csv files of equal size.

This is the code I am using:

```
n = 14 # defining the number of chunks
 
df = split(df_t3, factor(sort(rank(row.names(df))%%n))) # breaking into 14 list

lapply(names(df), function(x){
   write.csv(df[[x]], paste(x, ".txt", sep = ""), row.names = FALSE) #creating csv files
})
```

I want to modify this as such each chunks capture an entire set records related to a same ID before breaking off the file.

For example ID10 = 300 rows, ID 20 = 500 rows. The files should capture entire 300 records before jumping into next chunk. I have more then 1mm ID's thus cannot use ID as an criteria to break into chunks.

Not sure if I am really clear in my request. Happy to provide more clarity. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IDs are even close to balanced, I would split into chunks of roughly the same number of IDs per chunk. Something like this:

```
ids = unique(df_t3$ID)
n_chunks = 14
id_chunk = ceiling(seq(1e-5, n_chunks, length.out = length(ids)))

for(i in seq_len(n_chunks)) {
  write.csv(
    df_t3[df_t3$ID %in% ids[id_chunk == i], ],
    file = paste0("chunk", i, ".csv"),
    row.names = FALSE
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks Gregor. It works perfectly. I am new in R and trying to get more understanding on this code for learning purpose. Is the breakout defined in the id_chunk vector?

Comment: The `id_chunk` definition is perhaps a little too clever and a little too unclear. We want to create a vector that tells us for each ID, what chunk does it go in. So we use `seq` to create a sequence from *just* above 0 to `n_chunks`, where the length of the sequence is the number of IDs. Then we use `ceiling()` to round up to the nearest integer all of the numbers in the sequence. And this `id_chunk` is a vector, the same length as the number of IDs, that tells us for each ID what chunk should it go in.

Comment: It took me a few tries to get the `id_chunk` definition right, which is why I say it's perhaps too clever. Definitely worth at least a couple lines of comments in the code to explain what's happening. But I'm still pretty happy with it--since it's very likely the number of IDs is not divisible by the number of chunks, this seems like a quick way to group the IDs into bins of *almost* equal sizes.

Comment: makes perfect sense. thanks again